# Facebook Reporting API vs. Web Console Inconsistencies

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am having some consistency issues with the Facebook Graph API report stats. It seems that when I pull a report off the admin console in Facebook it is generally similar but not very close to the data I get when I post a request to the Graph API with the same parameters. For example, I pull a report for a campaign from the admin console and I get:

Impressions: 434,034
Clicks: 4,516
Spent: 2,810.73
Likes: 3,009

When I request the same data from the graph API I get:

Impressions: 418,000
Clicks: 4,280
Spent: 2,665.53
Likes: 2,918

Any idea why I would be having this issue and has anyone had something similar? The API request I made is below.

https://graph.facebook.com/act_xxx/adcampaignstats?access_token=xxx&start_time=2013-11-4T00:00:00&end_time=2013-11-10T23:59:59&limit=500

And the relevant portion of the response I get is:

{"id":"xxx/stats/xxx/xxx","campaign_id":xxx,"topline_id":0,"start_time":"2013-11-04T00:00:00+0000","end_time":"2013-11-10T23:59:59+0000","impressions":418000,"clicks":4280,"spent":266553,"social_impressions":122693,"social_clicks":28,"social_spent":2291,"unique_impressions":216356,"social_unique_impressions":42529,"unique_clicks":4280,"social_unique_clicks":28,"is_completed":false,"actions":{"comment":13,"like":2918,"photo_view":47,"post":30,"post_like":212},"inline_actions":{"title_clicks":0,"like":2670,"rsvp_yes":0,"rsvp_maybe":0,"post_like":0,"comment":0,"photo_view":0,"link_click":0,"video_play":0,"question_vote":0}}

Comment: Those use different data backends as far as I know and can't be directly compared - the Graph API, assuming you're using the correct timezone offsets, should be the same as the old reports, but not necessarily the new reports

Comment: That is very interesting..Is there someplace I can do some reading about how each backend derives its data? And is there a rule to follow about which one's data is better to show to clients?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, basically calls to '/stats/', etc should reflect the 'old reports' in the frontend, and the 'reportstats' endpoint should return the new reports interface - There may not actually be any discrepancies (assuming you're using the same timezones) but they do come from different interfaces

Comment: Just for follow up. The numbers matched up when I changed the requests from '/adcampaignstats/' to '/reportstats/' and made all the pertinent changes. In case someone had a similar issue. Thanks for all the help, Igy. :)